# Dart HttpClient.getUrl invoked by Timer without client or http server

Tags: dart, server-side, dart-async

**EDIT**: Problem wasn't related to Timer or HttpServer, it was dart.io sleep function pausing everything. It is clearly described in documentation, my bad.

//

I have weird problem with HttpClient working in server code. I call

```dart
client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url)).then((HttpClientRequest response) => response.close()).then(HttpBodyHandler.processResponse).then((HttpClientResponseBody body) {
    print(body.response.statusCode);
```

from Timer object and it never reach print step. 
It is almost copy and paste code from previous version, which wasn't called from Timer but from HttpRequest. Working code is in my question [here][1]. 
It fails on the long line, I suspect that it is a last Future it never reach (HttpClientResponseBody).

Timer object is created like this (just test code):

```dart
main() {
  t = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(minutes: period), (Timer t) => hit());

}

void hit() {
  if (new DateTime.now().hour == 17) {
    print("syncing rock");

    loadUrlBody(furl + filter).then((content) {
      print("content loaded");
```

//edit:
okay, here is the source, it might be some trivial problem..which I can't figure out for two days :-D

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http_server/http_server.dart';
import 'package:slack/slack_io.dart' as slack;

Timer t;
bool check;
final period = 1;
final furl = "https://****.tpondemand.com";
final filter = "somefilter";


main() {
  t = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(minutes: period), (Timer t) => hit());

}

void hit() {
  if (new DateTime.now().hour == 17) {
    print("syncing rock");

    loadUrlBody(furl + filter).then((content) {
      print("content loaded");
      Map parsedMap = content.body;
      handleMap(parsedMap);
    });
    sleep(new Duration(minutes: 60));
  } else {
    print("no time to rock " + new DateTime.now().toString());
    sleep(new Duration(minutes: period * 10));
  }
}

Future loadUrlBody(String url) {
  final c = new Completer();
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.addCredentials(Uri.parse("https://****.tpondemand.com/api"), "tprealm", new HttpClientBasicCredentials("user", "password"));
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url)).then((HttpClientRequest response) => response.close()).then(HttpBodyHandler.processResponse).then((HttpClientResponseBody body) {
    print(body.response.statusCode);
    c.complete(body);
  });
  return c.future;
}



void send2Slack(String m) {
  slack.Message message = new slack.Message()..text = m;

  slack.token = 'token';
  slack.team = 'team';
  slack.send(message);
}
void handleMap(Map valueMap) {

  final Duration lostInTime = new Duration(days: 30);
  var sb = new StringBuffer();
  sb.write('K o m p o s t \n');

  for (var item in valueMap["Items"]) {
    if (item['CreateDate'] == null) item['CreateDate'] = '/Date(1403167885000+0100)/';
    if (item['ModifyDate'] == null) item['ModifyDate'] = '/Date(1403167885000+0100)/';
    if (item['LastCommentDate'] == null) item['LastCommentDate'] = '/Date(1403167885000+0100)/';

    DateTime moonLanding = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse(item['CreateDate'].substring(6, 19)));
    DateTime modifyLanding = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse(item['ModifyDate'].substring(6, 19)));
    DateTime commentLanding = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse(item['LastCommentDate'].substring(6, 19)));
    DateTime lastChangeLanding = (modifyLanding.isBefore(commentLanding)) ? commentLanding : modifyLanding;
    Duration difference = new DateTime.now().difference(lastChangeLanding);

    if (moonLanding.add(lostInTime).isBefore(new DateTime.now()) && difference.inDays > 4) {
      sb
          ..write('<https://****.tpondemand.com/entity/')
          ..write(item['Id'])
          ..write('|')
          ..write(item['Name'])
          ..write('> last change: ')
          ..write(difference.inDays)
          ..write(' days ago \n');

    }
    ;


  }
  send2Slack(sb.toString());
  print("sent to Slack");
  sb.clear();
}
```

Comment: Your code fragments seem a bit disconnected. Can you create a minimal code example that allows to reproduce the problem?
You write `getUrl` from `Timer` doesn't work, but you call `hit()` from `Timer`. I assume you forgot some `return` or similar simple oversight, but it's hard to tell form your code.

Comment: The updated code is much better, but you should have stripped it down to a minimum that allows to reproduce the problem. Do you think `handleMap` and `send2Slack` are related to your problem? Where is the definition of `sleep`. You really should try to reduce your code so that the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce your problem is left. Most of the time this alone reveals the cause of the problem.

Comment: okay, working on it, seems that sleep freeze all processes and it caused freeze of the request in the middle :)

Comment: Can you add the implementation of `sleep()` to your question? `sleep` seems weird. I think you try something that doesn't work well in Dart. Dart doesn't provide something like `sleep` itself because it doesn't fit well in the async programming model. I guess you'll need another approach. If I can have a look at your code I might be able to make a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created similar code but I can't reproduce your problem.
So basically this does work when called from a `Timer`.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http_server/http_server.dart';

Timer t;
final period = 1;

void main(args) {
  t = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(minutes: period), (Timer t) => hit());
}

void hit() {
  loadUrlBody('http://www.google.com')
      .then((HttpClientResponseBody b) => print('hit: ${b.response.statusCode}'));
}

Future loadUrlBody(String url) {
  print('executing');
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  // commented out because I have no server where I can use it
  // HttpClient client = new HttpClient()              
  //    ..addCredentials(Uri.parse("https://****.tpondemand.com/api"), "tprealm", new HttpClientBasicCredentials("user", "password"));
  return client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url))        // <== return is important here
      .then((HttpClientRequest response) => response.close())
      .then(HttpBodyHandler.processResponse)
      .then((HttpClientResponseBody body) {
        print('body: (${new DateTime.now()}) ${body.response.statusCode}');
        return body;                         // <== this value is the value the next 'then' receives. 
// for example x in: loadUrlBody('http://someurl').then(x) => doSomething(x)); 
      });
}
```

You don't need to use a `Completer`. Completer are for more complicated used cases where for example one method returns a Completer and for example an eventHandler completes it.

You just have to ensure that you return a `Future` everywhere. `then` always returns a `Future`. The value of the returned `Future` is the value returned inside `then`.

Comment: Thanks for simplifying my code, I've misunderstood the concept of Completer. My problem was related to sleep function, I thought that Future is kind of thread, but it is not and sleep paused it.

Comment: An `Isolate` is the most similar to a thread in Dart. `Future` is about async programming. This means that while some code is waiting for a response (for example an I/O operation delegated to the operating system) other code can be executed. It is a time sharing model. All code within one isolate runs on the same CPU core. `Future` can also be seen as a simpler API for callbacks.